# Populate textarea with special characters after jQuery GET request

Tags: jquery

When populating a textarea with special characters from a jQuery GET request, the special characters display as html codes. Eg. `&eacute; rather than é.`

The PHP file is outputting the text using htmlentities. Eg. `echo htmlentities($text);`

The pertinent part of jQuery request is here:

```
success:function(data){
     $('textarea').val(data);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
success:function(data){
     $('textarea').html(data);
}
```

Does that work? Can't think, off the top of my head, but it *should*.

Comment: Thanks SpoonNZ, but when I've tried it, I run into other problems... Also according to the jQuery API: "The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea." I thought this might be the case with setting the value as well...

Comment: Yes, but you don't want to set the value to "&eaucte;", which is what you're passing it. Either don't `htmlentities()` the data (which is the easiest method), or don't use the `val()` function. How about `$('textarea')[0].innerHTML = data`?

Comment: OK, I've tested my original answer, seems to work perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/4UR7V/1/ - can you provide more detail on the problems?

Comment: Ah, thanks for explaining the difference between `val()` and `html()`. I'll use `html()` and try and figure out the subsequent problems (not to do with the special characters). Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Use `Jquery` `html` function instead of `val`:

```
success:function(data){
     $('textarea').html(data);
}
```

`val` will assign the "escaped" value, you want the HTML representation - `html`.

Watch [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zbK9u/) JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#test").val($("<div>").html(data).text());
});
```